# Samsung Galaxy S i897 not detected by PC

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, usb

I have read every forum and every "help" site on Samsung's website and all over the internet. Nothing has worked. I bought an unlocked Galaxy S i897 on ebay, originally an AT&T phone but I'm using it on T-mobile. Is this potentially the problem? I've tried 2 different cords, only charges, never recognized in any Kies version and never recognized by PC like step 3 on this page says it should.

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/SupportOwnersFAQPopup.do?faq_id=FAQ00045584&fm_seq=46246

Extremely frustrated at this point. I don't think calling t-mobile can help because the phone was AT&T. Samsung probably wouldn't help either because I bought it on ebay. Unless you think they would, then let me know. I just want to add music and transfer files back and forth, backup contacts, etc., and most importantly update my firmware (currently has Froyo).

Comment: What OS version do you have?

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (the OP hasn't visited the site anymore after 10 years and no answers have been voted). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from potential issues from your current OS version, installed drivers, etc, you can look at this problem from your phone's side.

Assuming that the problem doesn't lie with Kies, Windows 7 or the drivers in use:

1. Before connecting your phone to the computer, open the keypad and dial `*#7284#`;
2. You will see a menu for UART and USB;
3. Under USB, select PDA. If PDA is already selected, select MODEM and then back to PDA;
4. Don't worry about USB debugging or anything, just connect your phone to the PC
   Everything will work as it is intended to whether you use Kies, no Kies or just Mass storage.

This is a known problem with Samsung, the PDA mode for the USB connection needs to be active. And when active, sometimes we need to reset it by selecting something else and then PDA again.

Comment: Thank you for an answer that is finally not just another forum with the same "solution". But it didn't work. So what are some of the other factors that could be causing it that I can look into?

Comment: I have Windows 7 home premium version 6.1 SP1

Comment: @pferdesindgut Can you specify which part didn't work? You dial the code and the menu was presented and you've selected an option and after connecting the phone to your PC again, It wasn't recognized? Or the menu wasn't presented when the code was dialed?

Comment: I dialed the code, plugged into PC again, and it was still not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Please download and install the Samsung drivers - if you're using a 64 bit computer, use the 64 bit drivers, otherwise use the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 0):

What type of OS do you use? On W10 Home it simply does not work, try on any W10 Pro. I had the same issue before, very annoying :(